# Paper trail manual versioning isn't working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

I'm using the `paper_trail` gem. My use case involves creating versions when I explicitly want to instead of on callbacks like `on: [:update]` or something.

I did so by adding `on: []` in my `my_model.rb` and using `paper_trail.touch_with_version` on my model instance. The problem is whenever I do this the first time the version is saved with `nil` attributes. Weird enough, the next time call `paper_trail.touch_with_version` it saves it correctly with all attributes correctly initialised.

Sample logs from my rails console:

```
document = Document.first
 #<Document:0x0000123456
id: 1,
name: "Sample document">

document.paper_trail.touch_with_version

document.versions.last.reify.name
=> nil

document.paper_trail.touch_with_version

document.versions.last.reify.name
=> "Sample document"
```

What's really peculiar  is that if I try doing `document.paper_trail.touch_with_version` followed by `document.versions.last.reify.name` I correctly get name of my document but if I exit console and repeat this process the first time the attributes of the object saved in that version is again `nil`.

I'm probably doing something obvious but didn't find anything on wiki that talks about this. Can someone explain to me where I'm messing up?

Update: I traced back the code in `paper_trail` library and found where the issue is. I found the anomaly in `record_trail.rb`:

```
# @api private
def attribute_in_previous_version(attr_name)
  if @in_after_callback && RAILS_GTE_5_1
    @record.attribute_before_last_save(attr_name.to_s)
  else
    @record.attribute_was(attr_name.to_s)
  end
end
```

So in console the `@record.attribute_before_last_save(attr_name.to_s)` is giving me `nil` but if I try `@record.attribute_was('name')` in my console it gives me the correct attribute(in this case name) of the record.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/1047 and https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/pull/1048