# Rails Active Record: 'attribute_before_last_save' vs 'attribute_was'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I was debugging a issue I was [facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599246/paper-trail-manual-versioning-isnt-working-as-expected) and I was struggling to understand why `attribute_before_last_save` works differently than `attribute_was` since in [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html#method-i-attribute_before_last_save) all I could get is that `attribute_before_last_save`  behaves similarly to `attribute_was` but in my case I'm getting `nil` for one and correct value for another.

Answer (score 11):

`attibute_before_last_save` only works after you save data to the database successfully.

If you have a callback before saving, you should use `attibute_was`.

Comment: it also won't work for a json column unless that column gets updated.  So updating just a non-json column will make `attibute_before_last_save` return nil for all json attributes

Answer (score 4):

> **attribute_before_last_save(attr_name)**: Returns the original value of an attribute before the last save. 
>   Behaves similarly to attribute_was. This method is useful in **after** 
>   **callbacks** to get the original value of an attribute before the save
>   that just occurred

Just **after callback** is affected by them

Assume User model has `name` attribute:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_update :find_name_before_last_save

  def find_name_before_last_save
    puts "+++++++++++++++"
    puts name_before_last_save
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on `after callback` part?

Comment: Yes, I can. FYI attribute_was is deprecated and will be replaced by attribute_before_last_save in Rails 5.1.4. I've updated the answer, you can check it

Answer (score 3):

When looking at the source for `attribute_was` in Rails 5.1.4 you will find this line

```
emit_warning_if_needed("attribute_was", "attribute_before_last_save")
```

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a77dd1fb74464b459b3c6034d6446029370848bb/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb#L248) it raises a following deprecation error

> The behavior of `attribute_was` inside of after callbacks will
>                 be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the
>                 behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what
>                 it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `attribute_before_last_save`
>                 instead.

Comment: I [looked it up](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a77dd1fb74464b459b3c6034d6446029370848bb/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb#L248) , it just raises deprecation warning

Comment: I'm interested in what could possibly be going wrong in `attribute_before_last_save` that's giving me `nil` while in `attribute_was` is giving me the correct attribute value.

Comment: @AbhinavSrivastava isn't it a new record? Could you update your question with your code?

Answer (score 0):

where is an excerpt from my code (with comment that shows what it outputted during the test) and what I have decided to use

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable,
         :async, :authentication_keys => [:email]

  after_update :save_old_email_in_history, if: :saved_change_to_email? # XXX: check the rails documentation for saved_change_to_ATTRIBUTE?

  def save_old_email_in_history
    # https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html
    #
    # puts(
    #   {
    #     previous_changes: previous_changes,
    #     email_was: email_was,
    #     email: email,
    #     saved_change_to_email: saved_change_to_email,
    #     email_before_last_save: email_before_last_save,
    #   }.to_s
    # )

    # In test outputs

    # {
    #   :previous_changes=>{
    #     "email"=>["idella@koelpin-rodriguez.com", "wanita_jakubowski@gottlieb.com"],
    #     "confirmed_at"=>[Mon, 01 Nov 2021 13:29:47 EDT -04:00, Mon, 01 Nov 2021 13:30:02 EDT -04:00],
    #     "unconfirmed_email"=>["wanita_jakubowski@gottlieb.com", nil],
    #     "updated_at"=>[Mon, 01 Nov 2021 13:29:57 EDT -04:00, Mon, 01 Nov 2021 13:30:02 EDT -04:00]
    #   },
    #   :email_was=>"wanita_jakubowski@gottlieb.com",
    #   :email=>"wanita_jakubowski@gottlieb.com",
    #   :saved_change_to_email=>["idella@koelpin-rodriguez.com", "wanita_jakubowski@gottlieb.com"],
    #   :email_before_last_save=>"idella@koelpin-rodriguez.com"
    # }

    UserEmailHistoryItem.create!(user: self, email: email_before_last_save)
  end
```